# cordova/phonegap inappbrowser wont open links correctly

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, inappbrowser

When I open a link with `_system`, it opens the Chrome browser on Android, but it doesn't navigate to the URL.

When I open the link with `_blank`, it opens the webview but also opens the Chrome browser taking me out of the app. When I return to the app, the in app webview has been opened to the link.

```
android 10 on pixel 4
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser v3.1.0 and 3.0.0 (going to try more versions)
phonegap v9.0.0.

window.open(link, '_system');
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(link);
```

The code worked on the app before, but now that I'm updating it, it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing same(_blank) problem in ios 13.

Now I'm using below plugin for load web view in side app.

 `cordova-plugin-browsertab` 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-browsertab

Code:

```
var strURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
cordova.plugins.browsertab.openUrl(strURL)
```

Comment: That plugin works for in-app browser, but there are no options to show a close/back button, so the user could "get stuck" in it. Ideally I would use _system, which that plugin doesn't seem to offer. Interesting that it does work though.